# Deserializing 'Vector t' as a returned RpcResult object in Telegram client

Tags: api, serialization, telegram

When making a telegram client method call of `contacts.getStatus` the return value is of type `RpcResult`.

An `RpcResult` is defined as:

```
rpc_result#f35c6d01 req_msg_id:long result:Object = RpcResult;
```

Which means there is a message id and an Object. The Object then must be deserialized based on the data type extracted from the first 4 bytes of the Object. That is fine, it works for all returned `RpcResult` objects so far except one: `contact.getStatuses`.

The returned data looks like it should, except the `Object` type is `Vector t`.

```
-->('get_server_answer: method: ', 'contacts.getStatuses')
<--('TL tl_elem.type: ', u'RpcResult')

<--('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'long')
<--('TL deserialize: subtype  = ', None)

<--('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'Object')
<--('TL tl_elem.type: ', u'Vector t')
```

Since vectors are a collection of items of type `t` we need to know what type `t` represents, but there is nothing in the returned data that indicates this.

Since the published return type of `contacts.getStatuses` is that of type `Vector<ContactStatus>` I can hard code the type of `t` to be `ContactStatus` but only because I know the type of `t` before making the call. IMHO this would be a bad solution as it assumes prior knowledge when deserializing incoming data.

How can I know the type of `Vector t` when returned as an object in an RpcResult?

BTW: if I deserialize the next 4 bytes of the incoming data the value is zero. This could mean there are zero items in the vector. But that still doesn't help me determine what data type `t` should be in the event there *are* items in the vector.

**Here is another way of looking at this from the byte stream perspective:**

Bytes returned from the telegram server:

```
0  | 01 6D 5C F3 00 E4 D0 22
8  | AF 90 34 58 15 C4 B5 1C
16 | 00 00 00 00
```

Since the first four bytes are **F3 5C 6D 01** (little endian order) that indicates an `RpcResult` data type has been returned:

```
rpc_result#f35c6d01 req_msg_id:long result:Object = RpcResult;
```

Which means I am now expecting a `long` (req_msg_id) and an `Object` (result).

So the next 8 bytes (long) should be the req_msg_id: **00 E4 D0 22 AF 90 34 58**

The next four bytes indicate the returned `Object` type: **1C B5 C4 15**
...which is a `Vector`:

```
vector#1cb5c415 {t:Type} # [ t ] = Vector t;
```

That leaves only the last four bytes, which are zero: **00 00 00 00**

Does this mean there are zero items in the vector?

If this was not zero, how would I determine (from the byte stream) what the data type in the vector is?

**Here is the full byte stream starting with the previous successful method call (user.getFullUser), followed by the method call whos result I'm having trouble deserializing (contacts.getStatuses) because the type in the Vector is not identified:**

```
('method_call: ', 'users.getFullUser', {'id': {'inputPeerSelf': {}}})
--> send_message: sending...

<-- Result:
('TL tl_elem.type: ', u'RpcResult')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'long')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'Object')
 0 | 01 6D 5C F3 00 F4 FD 94  <-- RpcResult (F3 5C 6D 01)
 8 | F6 F0 35 58 03 FC 32 59
16 | 00 00 00 00 9A 97 0D D1
24 | 57 04 00 00 61 1F 02 00
32 | 60 BA 2D 1C 69 6E 9F C4
40 | 05 4B 65 6E 6E 79 00 00
48 | 05 43 61 73 6F 6E 00 00
56 | 0B 31 32 30 36 35 35 30
64 | 30 30 34 39 49 39 B9 ED
72 | 06 F2 35 58 4C 48 CE 3A
80 | AD D3 ED FE 47 92 4F 5F
88 | 9A 97 0D D1 57 04 00 00
96 | 61 1F 02 00 60 BA 2D 1C
104 | 69 6E 9F C4 05 4B 65 6E
112 | 6E 79 00 00 05 43 61 73
120 | 6F 6E 00 00 0B 31 32 30
128 | 36 35 35 30 30 30 34 39
136 | 49 39 B9 ED 06 F2 35 58
144 | C0 A4 CD 9A 01 00 00 00
152 | 00 00 00 00 07 64 65 66
160 | 61 75 6C 74

('TL tl_elem.type: ', u'UserFull')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'#')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'User')

('TL tl_elem.type: ', u'User')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'#')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'true')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'int')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'long')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'string')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'string')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'string')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'UserStatus')

('TL tl_elem.type: ', u'UserStatus')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'int')

('TL tl_elem.type: ', u'contacts.Link')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'ContactLink')

('TL tl_elem.type: ', u'ContactLink')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'ContactLink')

('TL tl_elem.type: ', u'ContactLink')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'User')

('TL tl_elem.type: ', u'User')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'#')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'true')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'int')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'long')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'string')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'string')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'string')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'UserStatus')

('TL tl_elem.type: ', u'UserStatus')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'int')

('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'PeerNotifySettings')
('TL tl_elem.type: ', u'PeerNotifySettings')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'#')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'true')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', 'false')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'int')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'string')

-----------------------------------------------------
('user.getFullUser: ', 
{u'req_msg_id': 6356251390955615232L,
u'result': {u'link': 
{u'user': {u'last_name': 'Cason', u'status': {u'expires': 1479930374}, u'first_name': 'Kenny', u'bot_nochats': False, u'verified': False, 

u'bot_chat_history': False, u'min': False, u'deleted': False, u'restricted': False, u'self': True, u'bot': False, u'phone': '12069500049', 

u'contact': False, u'flags': 1111, u'bot_inline_geo': False, u'access_hash': -4278579723255301539L, u'mutual_contact': False, u'id': 139109}, 

u'my_link': {}, u'foreign_link': {}}, u'notify_settings': {u'show_previews': True, u'mute_until': 0, u'sound': 'default', u'flags': 1, u'silent': 

False}, u'flags': 0, u'user': {u'last_name': 'Cason', u'status': {u'expires': 1479930374}, u'first_name': 'Kenny', u'bot_nochats': False, 

u'verified': False, u'bot_chat_history': False, u'min': False, u'deleted': False, u'restricted': False, u'self': True, u'bot': False, u'phone': 

'12069500049', u'contact': False, u'flags': 1111, u'bot_inline_geo': False, u'access_hash': -4278579723255301539L, u'mutual_contact': False, 

u'id': 139109}, u'blocked': False}})
-----------------------------------------------------

('method_call: ', 'contacts.getStatuses', {})
--> send_message: sending...

<-- Result:
('TL tl_elem.type: ', u'RpcResult')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'long')
('TL deserialize: type     =  ', u'Object')
 0 | 01 6D 5C F3 00 2C 87 B6  <-- RpcResult
 8 | F9 F0 35 58 15 C4 B5 1C
16 | 00 00 00 00
```

At this point my original question remains: how to determine the type of the vector received above?

Comment: See my extended answer below using your provided data

Comment: Thank you but I don't see your extended answer. What am I missing. :-(

Comment: I see your answer now, sorry for my impatience. The bytes you decoded are for the method that actually works, the one called before my problem method. Glad you got the same decoding but that doesn't answer the question. What happens when you try to decode: 0x01 6D 5C F3 00 2C 87 B6  F9 F0 35 58 15 C4 B5 1C 00 00 00 00

Comment: is this a complete frame? `0x01 6D 5C F3 00 2C 87 B6 F9 F0 35 58 15 C4 B5 1C 00 00 00 00`

Comment: `iex(4)> x = 0x016D5CF3002C87B6F9F0355815C4B51C00000000`

`iex(5)> TL.hex x                                      
{%TL.Rpc_Result{req_msg_id: 6356251404403158016, result: %TL.Unknown{}},
 <<21, 196, 181, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0>>}`

Comment: Yes, that is a complete frame. I guess I'll have to account for a vector with zero items. The more I think about it this makes sense, but it was unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a portion of my decoder for handling Vectors (written in Elixir)

You might get an array of types simply packed end-to-end, in that case i use `dec_o` variant, where I check the expected type against the header of the binary to be decoded, I keep doing this until i have removed N number of a given type from the received byte stream - this is the way i can decode an list of types where a vectore header was not given with a count.

The second method is simpler, you have a leading type header , a vector header and a count of expected items. In this case I call the `dec_v` variant as listed below

Hope this helps...

```
  defp decode([type], <<21, 196, 181, 28, cnt::little-4*8, bin::binary>>), do: dec_v(type, bin, cnt, [])
  defp decode([_typ], <<code::little-4*8, _::binary>> = bin), do: dec_o(code, bin, [])
  defp decode(_, bin), do: decode(bin)
  defp decode(bin, flag, ix) when band(flag, ix) == ix, do: decode(bin)
  defp decode(bin, _, _), do: {nil, bin}
  defp decode(type, bin, flag, ix) when band(flag, ix) == ix, do: decode(type, bin)
  defp decode(_, bin, _, _), do: {nil, bin}
  defp dec_v(_, e, 0, acc), do: {Enum.reverse(acc), e}
  defp dec_v(_,"", _, acc), do: {Enum.reverse(acc),""}
  defp dec_v(type, bin, cnt, acc) do
    {v, e} = decode(type, bin)
    dec_v(type, e, cnt - 1, [v | acc])
  end
  defp dec_o(c0, <<c1::little-4*8, _::binary>> = bin, acc) when c0 != c1, do: {Enum.reverse(acc), bin}
  defp dec_o(c0, <<c1::little-4*8, _::binary>> = bin, acc) when c0 == c1 do
    {v, e}= decode(bin)
    dec_o(c0, e, [v | acc])
  end
```

**More Examples**

Applying this to the actual data from the problem above:

```
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.1] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10]

Interactive Elixir (1.3.4) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> x = 0x016D5CF300F4FD94F6F0355803FC3259000000009A970DD157040000611F020060BA2D1C696E9FC4054B656E6E790000054361736F6E00000B31323036353530303034394939B9ED06F235584C48CE3AADD3EDFE47924F5F9A970DD157040000611F020060BA2D1C696E9FC4054B656E6E790000054361736F6E00000B31323036353530303034394939B9ED06F23558C0A4CD9A01000000000000000764656661756C74

iex(3)> TL.hex x
{%TL.Rpc_Result{req_msg_id: 6356251390955615232,
  result: %TL.UserFull{about: nil, blocked: nil, bot_info: nil, flags: 0,
   link: %TL.Contacts.Link{foreign_link: %TL.ContactLinkUnknown{},
    my_link: %TL.ContactLinkNone{},
    user: %TL.User{access_hash: 14168164350454250080, bot: nil,
     bot_chat_history: nil, bot_info_version: nil, bot_inline_geo: nil,
     bot_inline_placeholder: nil, bot_nochats: nil, contact: nil, deleted: nil,
     first_name: "Kenny", flags: 1111, id: 139105, last_name: "Cason", min: nil,
     mutual_contact: nil, phone: "12065500049", photo: nil, restricted: nil,
     restriction_reason: nil, self: true,
     status: %TL.UserStatusOnline{expires: 1479930374}, username: nil,
     verified: nil}},
   notify_settings: %TL.PeerNotifySettings{flags: 1, mute_until: 0,
    show_previews: true, silent: nil, sound: "default"}, profile_photo: nil,
   user: %TL.User{access_hash: 14168164350454250080, bot: nil,
    bot_chat_history: nil, bot_info_version: nil, bot_inline_geo: nil,
    bot_inline_placeholder: nil, bot_nochats: nil, contact: nil, deleted: nil,
    first_name: "Kenny", flags: 1111, id: 139105, last_name: "Cason", min: nil,
    mutual_contact: nil, phone: "12065500049", photo: nil, restricted: nil,
    restriction_reason: nil, self: true,
    status: %TL.UserStatusOnline{expires: 1479930374}, username: nil,
    verified: nil}}}, ""}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I'm not very good at reading Elixer. If you can elaborate the details generically that would be helpful. Are they documented somewhere? The bottom line is: I've received back an Object data type that decodes to a type of `Vector t`. What bytes must I now decode to determine what type `t` is and how many of them there are?

Comment: here is the thing, two possibilities: identical object types stacked end to end, one after the other, so each object starts with its header field, you stop reading objects when the next header field changes. 
The second way is with a with an actual vector indicator followed by a 4 byte integer that signifies the count. this is straight forward as you will have N number of objects to decode from the byte stream

Comment: I edited my original post to add the actual bytes being returned from the server. As you can see it indicates a Vector is being returned and, maybe, there are zero items in the Vector. I can deal with that, but what if there are more than zero items in the vector? From the data above there is nothing indicating the type of those items. :-(

Comment: I added a full byte stream to my question above, which includes the method for which I have a question and the method previous to it. As far as I can tell there is nothing indicating the type of `t` in `Vector t`.

Comment: Another thing comes to mind, whats the result of running `contacts.getContacts#22c6aa08 hash:string = contacts.Contacts;` ? If this is a new number for which you have not synced/uploaded any contacts, i wonder if indeed you are infact seeing the correct results, no?

Comment: I haven't created any contacts from this client. I've been assuming the contacts from the iPhone client would be available from any client but I just realized this client is calling the telegram **test** server, not the production server. Silly me, I should have thought of this sooner! I think a vector of zero contacts makes sense now, how embarrassing.